# I give the absolute path but java cannot a class

Tags: junit, classpath

I cannot understand why this

`ioannis@ioannis-GA-MA74GM-S2H:~$ java -cp /opt/junit4.6/junit-4.6.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore /opt/CalculatorTest`

gives the error:

```
Could not find class: /opt/CalculatorTest
```

and this work fine:

```
ioannis@ioannis-GA-MA74GM-S2H:~$ java -cp /opt/junit4.6/junit-4.6.jar:/opt org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
JUnit version 4.6
.
Time: 0.005

OK (1 test)
```

in the first I give the full path for class /opt/CalculatorTest

Comment: fully qualified class names are specified in `<package>.<subpackage>.Class` format. If CalculatorTest has `package opt;` declared in its source file, then you should refer to it as `opt.CalculatorTest` from the directory where opt directory is present or opt directory is within classpath.

Comment: Try `opt.CalculatorTest` instead of `/opt/CalculatorTest`

Comment: The class CalculatorTest is not inside a package

Answer (score 1):

The classname is intended to be just the class name, not a path.  If it is in a package, you can have foo.Bar.  If it is in the default package, you can only have Bar.

As you noticed, the classpath is the place to identify the physical directories Java should look in to find the class.